# localizing notification in firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to localize push notifications sent through fcm.

Consider an example of sending messages about change in status of a todo. A todo has a title and a state (`OPEN` / `IN_PROGRESS` / `DONE`). I would like to be able to send a message with the following content:

`<string name="todo_status_changed">Status of %1$s changed to %2$s.</string>`

where the first parameter is the todo name and second is the todo state.

The message should be displayed to the user like this "Status of vacuuming changed to done." Where "vacuuming" is the title that is not translated and "done" is a translation of the `DONE` status.

This is how far I got with the fcm api:

```
"body_loc_key": "todo_status_changed",
"body_loc_args": [
   "vacuuming",
   "DONE" // I need to translate this
]
```

The problem I didn't figure out is how to translate a string from `body_loc_args`.

So the question is, how do I make this work with the following?

- fcm
- android
- ios

Surely there is a better way than creating one message for each todo status which would become very repetitive (although now that I think about it would give people translating the messages more context about the sentence and would probably be better for conjugations and etc):

```
<string name="todo_status_changed_to_in_progress">Status of %1$s changed to in progess.</string>
<string name="todo_status_changed_to_done">Status of %1$s changed to done.</string>
... messages for all other possible statuses
```

Comment: I came to the conclusion this is not possible because there are many languages where this would not work, so they make you write the full sentence.